# Search Bar for Xubuntu panel?

Tags: xubuntu, panel, xfce

Is there an applet for the Xubuntu panel that's similar to the search bar on OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It's called Linelight.

Install the package `sudo apt-get install xfce4-linelight-plugin`

Then add the Linelight applet to the Panel

[image]